# MYSql connection in TypeScript Error: No overload matches this call?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I have MySql2 DB config function

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
 host: process.env['SQL_HOST'],
  user: process.env['SQL_USER'],
  password: process.env['SQL_PASSWORD'],
});
```

I get this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(connectionUri: string): Connection', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ host: string | undefined; user: string | undefined; password: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(config: ConnectionOptions): Connection', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ host: string | undefined; user: string | undefined; password: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConnectionOptions' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties.
      Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Has anyone got this error?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` set to true, see [explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes), and keeping that in mind and seeing that `process.env` has all values as `string | undefined` you need to do something like this:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
 host: process.env['SQL_HOST'] ?? '',
  user: process.env['SQL_USER'] ?? '',
  password: process.env['SQL_PASSWORD'] ?? '',
})
```

Or turn off the option `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in `tsconfig.json`.

You can play with this option [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQggsxMDyADnpgM7IDeAsAFDIOMMD0AVK3U168gCoAWKALIBPAMoBFADLIArmWjIw6ZHFlhB4YAjiRVZTl0atmho-OgB%20AFzIyYKKADmAbjpmubDvSMMeAlCI4MjIAd3QoABNkdBglfl1kUUkZCygPblMfIyCQ8KibOwdnN1oMxi9y42QAOTgAWxRY%20JRI3TgAI2CUZTkFZBgI%20OAKBExsXHwQKr8s32Q2sE7uwvtHEFd3bM92GeR-QWQEBKgFMAGhjRQxrBxSEAA6Pn4R5FedABsPiGiAcjGvropr83iAWsgUgBab4ANwgHxicWS0mQAAoPsAANYodQwAAcAH0nBBsFA4B8CQhgABKB57HgASTicAh0mhEDhCOOcFOEHOrzIRBwwBgwB%20aIx2LkYHx9Q6ABZqS0wVcFhB4LIPucAR8gZgLlB4olubz%20RQLJE6dtuGiACLqtRa2y-ACqvAAYoSAOIAURqPoASgBBKQE1AM37U%20lzXwms6rYobUozSrWpgHFD8dD2EANJpxVWLZb9EToWSqKDXcZ3ZxKdBPVH2jVO5AfdCfLP2KNp4wxoydsAJ9abMo95Cp%20b7Z6BCLnECyOWKXo3CbnZQNpuOsC2ADMO4ADAA2buTkwzIizwrzxdQZNjifzDN2MtQJDIBkABVUkUilZCdb6FBBkNXhUC-Fca0waMZjbT4gx-P8yCHEotnmB9fCfIINAAllZBAYAAA8FnQeo4FAZ8EGxNcVAg3A6yeAB1TRAOiAdVBAaILygc4eRQYAnBACIfmgscyHbKiP10fhkKTVDfHQownzwRoAC9MBxBRol6ewhNbdtyQWXQIDIDcHU1bdkF%20WDyUjET5mUiA1OwGSnGQAAfSzrI%20X47zQ3YxynAJkHqYAvhGHBMEiCgOnVXSWQcstznbBBZFOBZUtrVVQGAPADNo%204ANVZEZAUKA4SgUzmwsgBGfc7AijiyBPR8%20y4fLeGARpEqvBcYtvOSjAUm0xETJwRREGIOgAKzuChQHsCA4GiZobnKvANgAmFyVkYzKq3Z14A%20BRbICs9RNG8aCGm2bCg6dB0G%20OAQF8%20T-NPZAgy%20dBQiOatJg23pitBewnqQCgNESYJMQNcEHuiVF5pwVKICVNQri0HQCsaDR0EtO0zJbQ6FGajDWqYRGUsrIN1Gk2w7oexbnoGnZvHe%201ICgELsDmuIAQXMEto%20HaKDILNNWiGLfpANbxV6XM8DhZAACk4C2sQEEcEglBEIUTPfM1kEE85KzGepGg48VUSe6JSImpwVDgUI4Am5gjgSDY%20JVQ4YHUZGScUgDIhGTpvm1oUjmCdanAAGmQDp1GQUtyx0MFKcrcAPgmyIVDEmIwQgHLBENVV8qmGJDQARx2qAJtheE9vM2wHB2-3uHpZAAE0ywjsFyVzwVhRgCaWR9kBJn1VFRXhSJbCekRY%20wAiLNRJUAF4AD5kBhdBgEiNfN8oABfQOVFVMAdeuSPayT3kPhgK1T3bhigwDGoGRqL1bA7ggXSSF0xF4O%20GoAA1AgABpH04Igi8kNPIWs6lEQtH6BoSsQExQfGiKPceIA5pghvkceQyh6hhwgKgSOEcvhdEok8AIE0U550znHS%20XxxSYCQA-R87cp4YIeGsZwK8uHoMtPHGAMBoACNOgMIRDxiQkT5DXCRj9JG8VUBiboFBgL0nbtA0qDwdEQCkCSJwGgMCRB%20CNYcijHzIH0RVfRhiNgmNxj8AAQrIUR4jW7phsTyXR%20ivQQDkQ4EQwDtoQCsRhduXdk5PSkRxZAoQXjHCkdPAYeFsGJ27tgWWKgLBx1rvdTEtZdC2ADN9W07RJKUT5HoqA6BlDnyFA8AkjTSGRzsr4VpZD7C3Xuo9MEHlUSTyEbPEA89DYQCXrYFeyAN5bx3nvWZm857UheoNN61igwEJ0sQqu0AJrAVIucLB9wOlGD2TXd0EQjmFFRBckQtg%20EbFjoLYWoyRD73mbvNZLMn7MTMeSWsoRC5x34obXq0AKCohcQyL079AHW2QLaH04YhAhl%20kLeoOClTkULO0LoChY5JzsGLDByASQhx6C8Cg6ASBTHbo2AmFkiYozOVwMgsgiBcTAC4-iNQIWnF6QzJ6PymBDW8T6XMHQMQbTuthDlXLZy8qcPym8FBEUdD5QKixzgNERDBqC1y14%20pQphXCmoCL4nItReivmWKmoARiu3ckTsRAUErGAVK2BojBGVqrOA6tNbnB1RtdA11cBQs3I3AYfcUZPElSHWsCruXKtVSauOCdHowmcO3TVKrtWjQoEHMglLojAq%20MgD1XrDXgrVfoCEo1JozQjQwiaiSSQtDoU9I2TDVAIEpkZTO7dKxED-CSSAZaQUAG0VZqw1sALWabFBhubWAMgABdNE-AwBgCINYZgzAcCkQAEyHmPZCAArA8U2zAfRSDEBegkAAJXgQgpAPG3fUAAxGISCIACR4geBerx1RUSJO0PwZACQuUkgoO2r2EAJqTKQLLQ4U7ITHoAHoXp3LHAA1FhnDm6yQe2pLHepRdgXIMEG20KCJJZVqgN6%20tS7DQrtmhwjCzxXi0oKq8figlKzRBFHYTlKatV1teMW0tnHFJk0YHm1jIanBITpn0xmoqKgbK41c18rQjIkKhbwBkQgfQAKDEID8sdbRBl4D6YzpnrO2Z9EqXoDG%20RevFL6p5KnK1SSXMxUAMBdQTtBL0WdAb51awqZAdu7GI1PDIWCSWzcIDMBZeXdiFYyQTWaK0w2eZwYqGxBAIg9afMmS0ZIxlVVbAspA7MGYiwIDKdU3HdTsSPJBigDlgAPL8BzZneAWY-CCDyvwbN2cG2Nyyk2fS-HXpplg2mA4CFeOWhEo7QA8QraAU2xT4mJXtrWII1S115yKNndQsmbTRJ7qo3Of5ih0TMfHJwY0AYqFO1RQz%20SfEhAO9l52iDWlQoq65lQr3ZAjiUe9Gr%200Y1HVZadeTDAodOEKHPJb44Vs2gCaSIyIsliUSUGSA1%20ofQ9cuCoPbQszEUIRGQHK%20ZWzAA6GSGu5LwAkbfKiKymBXIgxJw4RAxlIxPDEBiJw27tHQEOaDQIFKtQHKGPUbM2pyRHQbi2VLDX9io9J6LoV-TsfiuqJ9NsP16jmQXaHeobqK6M6WJAc252hSV2riIJ4LjL6Vh9giYF2ENAjFjjlclBELwKAoMS3oKRQSrrLroYnmI9bw%20jfVtlTBrdalty153EBXdtfpib5mYrcfeKkCMJKvM-oFWC3AXzvQ8kUYC7EwsTK867X1m8dVR0vvZiZ9KnoKhpWIExBiewaoqqd4MCjmY9eVOFG631nzi3S9adZtY%20L5xA%20QZCJtnkeYOY0sNCyHzUsljZQ2rmRoiD982LqaKb4mfGD75cu5CEZAPjEHuGQO8KZy9qgAwPMmNyVEBIM6kfpfVYkeQcsF56l61Ylt8btvE1s5pzQFB-cElmJiUEhFZIhOUMRMYqxMUwQb9dp240D7s%204R8UAzhQRwQAADCQT3H-KYRgptO4R1FAOALlDEcUd3SEe5FA3sGYSAsgIMCQnrZ2Y3RmDwQ%20ZmSZblMLOXUXT-b-OlcgKgAAzfLjLZc-IYERMRQ0LMDBTKQ4D8d0AADUyw-DAVQDEGqmPS5zGDMU4kcC2j0GxHGSQG4hFG0AM0RVQC2V8LwFFGINn1PANyIBgAIhclN0AL8A%20iKGHCgzhnMJQA-B9CEBcOcXcOAE8JQG8JfwYG8PiPX2W10IDn0MbWaFyEFH4DJH6GAigQ8IM28MyxiIIhKP%20waKaIgHKNHD8iqJtBqNSNMKDgBgsOyNyLcKOGgDCICNiznzHFCMGJ0Pbh9ELkUDP1qMNAn2rxSN1UQSyJyJJFcPFGCPmL8PCMJ0KigEIREMa1WLgHfw8h8ynXXQSJGIlW2NPyONDX2Krzv0LROJmPOLyLQADCkChVQAWP8OIOQGAO3kxjLkry7B6I1g%20DeIBKcE%20O%20PbjGNrDMTIHnU1SmOuAXSLiK0Aky2QzpwgExKpMhXWPvESKnDu3oRoKllXBwiSHEBRFKnKgSULkSgf1pWgEYVHXQGzUmNclVF4OlK2wMyuN6GbnsCeDu1FjLDJR7WzmGEqxWPmErFXRdFzBpgiGABUh%20FkJFXkK2BOTLnylRF4ymFsAwFuGwTYPIGpFsG3l3m0NHGPgYC2G21ULfFtG0DAF614APk4CnW8MeVGnXVsEAQ8jwjMVFG9VKAUNHBuEnxJBhFsEjNwF61X1mSoEPjvGdJoB8AHFsELKnV%20BSGfQIAAV%20HXWjkMDSAbOlibJbP-kDA7K7J8HqPyBni5xhH7OkAJA-CDDEDEAYgIADFtGHLoEPm7CAA) where I added the definition of `ConnectionOptions` and `precess.env`